# Safari driver asking every time to enable "Allow Remote Automation" in selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, safaridriver

Safari driver throwing error "Allow Remote Automation".

I have already enabled in main safari window but when executing the selenium test it throws the same exception again and again.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try by running this command in your terminal to allow subsequent Webdriver sessions without further authentication

`sudo /usr/bin/safaridriver --enable`

Please know you would need sudo access on the machine.

Comment: Already did this. It open browser but "Allow Remote Automation" is unchecked in that.

Comment: I'm only shown the "This Safari window is remotely controlled by an automated test." message if I try to interact with the safari window using my mouse/keyboard. If I don't click on the window, the automation script continues to execute without problems.
What's the version of Safari on your machine?