# Enable safari driver in terminal from python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, terminal, safari

I would like to enable safari driver in each session separately.

```
import os
os.system("sudo safaridriver --enable")
```

Previous code asks for password.
My question is basically how to provide the asked password? I tried something like
import subprocess

```
p = subprocess.Popen(["sudo safaridriver --enable"], shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p.stdin.write(b"password\n")  # Assume that the password is indeed "password"
result = p.stdout.read()  # The program's output
print(result)
```

This code doesn't work. Throwing the following error:

```
sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper
```

So I'm not sure how to handle it.
Additionally it would be great if the password would not be in clear text. But for start clear text is ok.

Thanks for any ideas

ps related text without useful answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51397823/safari-driver-asking-every-time-to-enable-allow-remote-automation-in-selenium)

Comment: maybe `sudo` not read from `stdin` for security reason. But error shows that you could  use `-S` to read from `stdin` -- `sudo -S safaridriver --enable`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using sudo with Python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13045593/using-sudo-with-python-script)

Answer (score 1):

It seems `sudo` doesn't read from `stdin` - probably for security reason.

But error shows that you could use option `-S` in `sudo` to read from `stdin` .

Documentation `man sudo` shows

```
-S, --stdin
            Write the prompt to the standard error and read the password 
            from the standard input instead of using the terminal device.
```

I don't have `safaridriver` so I tested on something simpler like `ls`

In `bash` in console works for me

```
echo password | sudo -S ls
```

or

```
sudo -S ls <<< password
```

And first method works for me in code

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen(["echo password | sudo -S ls"], shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

result = p.communicate()[0].decode()

print(result)
```

But version with `<<<` has problem because `subprocess` uses `sh` instead of `bash`.
But it works with `executable='/bin/bash'`

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen(["sudo -S ls <<< password"], executable='/bin/bash', shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,)

result = p.communicate()[0].decode()

print(result)
```